# How to find the maximum tensor from multiple tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have a problem in understanding how tensors work for example i have created a tensor filled with zeros using

```
Enhanced = tf.zeros((m, n))
```

and i want to replace those zeros with elements from another tensor "lr_ip" using a for loop :

```
m, n, c = lr_ip.shape
Enhanced = tf.zeros((m, n))
for k in range(c):
    q = lr_ip[:, :, k]
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        for j in range(1, n+1):
            qi = q[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2]
            p_0 = abs(qi[1][1]*(1-qi[1][0]*qi[1][2]))
            p_45 = abs(qi[1][1]*(1-qi[2][0]*qi[0][2]))
            p_90 = abs(qi[1][1]*(1-qi[0][1]*qi[2][1]))
            p_135 = abs(qi[1][1]*(1-qi[0][0]*qi[2][2]))

            tensor_list = [p_0, p_45, p_90, p_135]
```

so i get stucked in this step , i wante the "Enhanced[i-1, j-1]" element to be replaced with the maximum tensor from "tensor_list"
i search in google and find some solution but none of them works for me, for example i tried that:

```
        max_tensor = tensor_list[0]
        for tensor in tensor_list[1:]:
            Enhanced[i-1, j-1] = torch.max(max_tensor,tensor)
```

but i get this error

```
TypeError: max() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Tensor), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input)
 * (Tensor input, Tensor other, *, Tensor out)
 * (Tensor input, int dim, bool keepdim, *, tuple of Tensors out)
 * (Tensor input, name dim, bool keepdim, *, tuple of Tensors out)
```

i also tried to use functools but it didn't work also , it gives me the same error.
thank you in advance

i think there is another way to solve the problem is by converting the tensor 'lr_ip' to an Eagertensor and then to a numpy but i didn't know how to implement it that way

Answer (score 0):

You need to use torch.maximum() instead of torch.max() when comparing two tensors.

Refer to

```
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.maximum.html
```

Comment: thank you for the response i tried this method but it rises a TypeError: maximum(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Tensor

Comment: You could start by replacing Enhanced = tf.zeros((m, n)) with Enhanced = torch.zeros((m, n)). You are mixing Tensorflow and Pytorch what is never a good practise and could result in weird error messages like this.

Comment: thank you @ranger, I used tf because the tensor where im taking the values is a tf tensor but i will try your answer.

Comment: yes as i expected @Ranger hence the "lr_ip" is a tf tensor it gives me the same error.